# Can we use dynamic data in a 3 tier architecture (database-DAL-BLL-User Interface)

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, dynamic-data

Can we use dynamic data in a 3 tier architecture (database-DAL-BLL-User Interface)
If we make any changes to generated file and add anotations will those chnages be lost when the edmx is updated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will lose changes you have made when the edmx is updated. Take a look at buddy classes if you want to make specific changes to generated files: http://hartzer.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/mvc-buddy-class/

Comment: can i use it in a 3 tier architecture (database-DAL-BLL-User Interface)

Comment: The architecture should work just fine. I'm making a sweeping statement as I'm unsure what your plans for it are. Take a look at these questions here to see if they offer clarification: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/43901/what-use-is-a-business-logic-layer-bll http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952534/communication-between-bll-and-dal